# 4 marbles are distributed among 7 children, what is the probability that at least 1 child has 3 or more marbles?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I've realized that if there are only $3$ marbles, then the probability would be $(1/7)(1/7)(1/7) = 1/343$, as each marble would have to go to the same person. How would one go about computing this for $4$ marbles and above?

Answer (score 0):

Let $n_{k}$ denote the number of marbles that the $k^{\text{th}}$ child receives $(k = 1, 2, \ldots, 7)$ so that the number of ways to distribute the $4$ balls is equal to the number of solutions to the equation

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{7} n_{k} = 4
\label{1}
\end{equation}

By a stars-and-bars argument, the number of solutions to the above equation is ${7 + 4 - 1\choose 7-1} = 210$.

Now let's count the number of solutions to $\sum_{k=1}^{7} n_{k} = 4$ in which at least one of the $n_{i}$'s is at least $3$. Place $3$ marbles into any one of the $7$ bins. This can be done in exactly $7$ ways since there are $7$ choices for the bin in which these $3$ marbles are placed in. Next, place the last marble into one of the $7$ bins in exactly $7$ ways (there are $7$ choices for a bin in which the last marble can be placed in). This gives us a total of $7\times 7 = 49$ ways to arrange our marbles with at least one bin containing $3$ marbles.

The probability required is just the ratio of desirable arrangements to total arrangements. This is given by $49/210$, or equivalently, $\boxed{7/30}$

Comment: The $210$ ways to distribute the marbles are not equally likely to occur.  For instance, there is only one way for all four marbles to be given to Esme.  On the other hand, if we have one blue marble, one black marble, one green marble, and one red marble, there are $4! = 24$ ways to give one marble each to Anne, Bruce, Clarence, and Denise.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to clarify: Each marble is considered the same

Comment: Regardless of the colors or what they are "considered," the stars and bars (distinguishable) outcomes are NOT equally likely unless you have very bizarre way of distributing the marbles "at random." Here's one way: write down all 210 outcomes and uniformly pick from that list. However that is not distributing marbles at random, it's picking from a list. Another way: each marble's probility of going to child $j$ is proportional to (1+ #marbles $j$ has). also NOT a  reasonable interpretation of "distributing marbles randomly."

Comment: My answer is wrong. I will remove it in 1 or 2 hours.